# A rod AB of length $l$ slides along two lines intersecting at P and inclined at angle $\theta$ . Find locus of circumcenter of $\triangle PAB$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider two straight lines $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ intersecting at a point P and inclined at a fixed acute angle $\theta$. If a rod $AB$ of fixed length $l$ slides along $L_{1},L_{2}$ such that $A$ always lies on $L_{1}$ and $B$ always lies on $L_{2}$,then

(A) the locus of the circumcenter of the triangle PAB is a circle

(B) area of the locus of circumcenter of the triangle PAB is  $\frac{1}{8}l^2\theta\ cosec^2\theta$

(C) the locus of circumcenter of the triangle PAB is the major segment of a circle

(D)area of the locus of circumcenter of the triangle PAB is  $\frac{1}{2}l^2\theta\ cosec^2\theta$

**My Attempt**

Taking the analytical approach(method of co-ordinates) I assumed P to be the origin $(0,0)$ and the line $L_{1}$ to be the x-axis.

Further I took point A as $(\alpha,0)$ and B as $(\beta,\beta\tan \theta)$.

If $R(h,k)$ be the circumcenter then circumcircle can be assumed as

$x^2+y^2-2hx-2ky=0$.

On putting coordinates of A and B in the circle and using the fact that $AB=l$

I eliminated $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and managed to obtain the equation(it was lot of rough work)

$h^2+k^2=\frac{l^2 \ cosec^2 \theta}{4}$

which indicates that the circumcenter $R(h,k)$ of triangle PAB lies on the circle

$x^2+y^2=\frac{l^2 \ cosec^2 \theta}{4}$

But I am not able to determine whether the circumcenter lies on the major or minor arc. What can we say about area.

Comment: I think the locus would be on the full circle but except a countable few points, when the circumcentre of $\triangle PAB$ is not defined as either $A$ or $B$ can overlap with $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, the sine law says that the circumradius $r$ of $\triangle PAB$ is given by

$$\begin{align*}
2r &= \frac{AB}{\sin \angle APB}\\
&= \frac{l}{\sin\theta}\quad\text{ or }\quad \frac{l}{\sin(\pi-\theta)}\\
r&= \frac{l \csc \theta}{2}
\end{align*}$$

So the circumcentre is always at $\frac{l \csc \theta}{2}$ away from $P$, the origin, and that distance is independent of the position of $AB$.

This matches your progress, though it doesn't confirm whether the locus is the full circle. My earlier comment was that the locus would miss a countable few points of the circle, when the circumcentre of $\triangle PAB$ is not defined as either $A$ or $B$ can overlap with $P$.